# Numpy: 1D array with various shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I try to understand how to handle a `1D` array (vector in linear algebra) with `NumPy`.

In the following example, I generate two `numpy.array` `a` and `b`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> b = np.array([[1],[2],[3]]).reshape(1,3)
>>> a.shape
(3,)
>>> b.shape
(1, 3)
```

For me, `a` and `b` have the same shape according linear algebra definition: 1 row, 3 columns, but not for `NumPy`.

Now, the `NumPy` `dot` product:

```
>>> np.dot(a,a)
14
>>> np.dot(b,a)
array([14])
>>> np.dot(b,b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: objects are not aligned
```

I have three different outputs.

**What's the difference between `dot(a,a)` and `dot(b,a)`? Why dot`(b,b)` doesn't work?**

I also have some differencies with those dot products:

```
>>> c = np.ones(9).reshape(3,3)
>>> np.dot(a,c)
array([ 6.,  6.,  6.])
>>> np.dot(b,c)
array([[ 6.,  6.,  6.]])
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Notice you are not only working with 1D arrays:

```
In [6]: a.ndim
Out[6]: 1

In [7]: b.ndim
Out[7]: 2
```

So, `b` is a 2D array.
You also see this in the output of `b.shape`: (1,3) indicates two dimensions as (3,) is one dimension.

The behaviour of `np.dot` is different for 1D and 2D arrays (from the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html)):

> For 2-D arrays it is equivalent to matrix multiplication, and for 1-D
>   arrays to inner product of vectors

That is the reason you get different results, because you are mixing 1D and 2D arrays. Since `b` is a 2D array, `np.dot(b, b)` tries a matrix multiplication on two 1x3 matrices, which fails.

---

With 1D arrays, np.dot does a inner product of the vectors:

```
In [44]: a = np.array([1,2,3])

In [45]: b = np.array([1,2,3])

In [46]: np.dot(a, b)
Out[46]: 14

In [47]: np.inner(a, b)
Out[47]: 14
```

With 2D arrays, it is a matrix multiplication (so 1x3 x 3x1 = 1x1, or 3x1 x 1x3 = 3x3):

```
In [49]: a = a.reshape(1,3)

In [50]: b = b.reshape(3,1)

In [51]: a
Out[51]: array([[1, 2, 3]])

In [52]: b
Out[52]:
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])

In [53]: np.dot(a,b)
Out[53]: array([[14]])

In [54]: np.dot(b,a)
Out[54]:
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 4, 6],
       [3, 6, 9]])

In [55]: np.dot(a,a)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-32e36f9db916> in <module>()
----> 1 np.dot(a,a)

ValueError: objects are not aligned
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Then what is the best practice if I want to do some linear algebra with numpy? Convert all my vector in 2D numpy.array? I'm a bit confused by two different shape...

Comment: I am not doing much linear algebra myself, but I think this depends on what you exactly want to do. Just vector products and other simple manipulations/calculations, then 1D is fine. If you want to do matrix calculation etc, you should use 2D.

Comment: The best strategy would be to use 1D arrays for vectors and 2D arrays to represent matrices. Constructions like 2D arrays with shape `(1,3)` are mainly needed for array magic, but not standard linear algebra stuff. In terms of linear algebra this would correspond to the not very useful object of a `1x3` matrix.