# About Numpy，a=np.array([1,2,3,4]),print a.shape[0]. why it will output 4?

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
print a.shape[0]
```

Why it will output `4`?

The array `[1,2,3,4]`, it's rows should be `1`, I think , so who can explain the reason for me?

Comment: The reason?  This is `numpy`, not `MATLAB`.  In `numpy` arrays may be 1d

Answer (score 2):

because

```
print(a.shape)  # -> (4,)
```

what you think (or want?) to have is

```
a = np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4]])
print(a.shape)  # -> (4, 1)
```

or rather (?)

```
a = np.array([[1, 2 , 3 , 4]])
print(a.shape)  # -> (1, 4)
```

Comment: Probably the author wants `a = np.array([[1,2,3,4]])` instead, because he expects first component of shape to be equal to 1

Comment: @alexisrozhkov: ooops, youre right. i'll include that.

Answer (score 1):

If you'll print `a.ndim` you'll get 1. That means that `a` is a one-dimensional array (has rank 1 in numpy terminology), with axis length = 4. It's different from 2D matrix with a single row or column (rank 2).

[More on ranks](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html#the-basics)

Related questions:

- [numpy: 1D array with various shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680593/numpy-1d-array-with-various-shape)
- [Python: Differentiating between row and column vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428621/python-differentiating-between-row-and-column-vectors)

Answer (score 0):

The shape attribute for numpy arrays returns the dimensions of the array. If a has n rows and m columns, then a.shape is (n,m). So a.shape[0] is n and a.shape[1] is m.

Answer (score 0):

numpy arrays returns the dimensions of the array. So, when you create an array using,

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
```

you get an array with 4 dimensions. You can check it by printing the shape,

```
print(a.shape) #(4,)
```

So, what you get is NOT a 1x4 matrix. If you want that do,

```
a = numpy.array([1,2,3,4]).reshape((1,4))
print(a.shape)
```

Or even better,

```
a = numpy.array([[1,2,3,4]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

by doing this, you get a `a` as a ndarray, and it is a one-dimension array. Here, the shape (4,) means the array is indexed by a single index which runs from 0 to 3. You can access the elements by the index 0~3. It is different from multi-dimensional arrays.

You can refer to more help from this link [Difference between numpy.array shape (R, 1) and (R,)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053050/difference-between-numpy-array-shape-r-1-and-r).