# Python stats.kstest bug?

Tags: python, scipy, p-value, kolmogorov-smirnov

I find the way to interpret the shape of random sample has big impact on kstest. I try the following codes:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

N = 260
np.random.seed(1)
X = np.random.rand(N)
Xarray = X.reshape(N,1)
XarrayT = Xarray.T

print('X' + str(X.shape) + ': ' + str(stats.kstest(X, 'uniform') ) )
print( 'Xarray' + str(Xarray.shape) + ':' + str( stats.kstest(Xarray, 'uniform') ) )
print( 'XarrayT' + str(XarrayT.shape) + ': ' + str( stats.kstest(XarrayT, 'uniform') ) )
```

It gives the results:

```
X(260,): KstestResult(statistic=0.052396054203786291, pvalue=0.46346349447418866)
Xarray(260, 1):KstestResult(statistic=0.99988562518265511, pvalue=0.0)
XarrayT(1, 260): KstestResult(statistic=0.99988562518265511, pvalue=0.00022874963468977327)
```

where X, Xarray, XarrayT have the same data, except that they have different shape. And the pvalues are totally different. Is it due to a bug or I miss some point in order to use kstest correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, [the scipy kstest documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kstest.html) tells us it should be a 1d array.

if we run the following:

```
print('X ' + 'ndimensions=' + str(X.ndim) + ' ' + (str(stats.kstest(X, 'uniform'))))
```

We see 1 dimensions in the target array.

output:

```
X ndimensions=1 KstestResult(statistic=0.052396054203786291, pvalue=0.46346349447418866)
```

However, when we try our other Xarray:

```
print('Xarray ' + 'ndimensions=' + str(Xarray.ndim) + ' ' + (str(stats.kstest(Xarray, 'uniform'))))

Xarray ndimensions=2 KstestResult(statistic=0.99988562518265511, pvalue=0.0)
```

This would indicate to me the use of two dimensions in the input array is screwing up the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test for goodness of fit.

I would also suggest reading the answers [at this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680593/numpy-1d-array-with-various-shape)

Comment: Thanks Dylan! I recognize the issue of 1-d array from the kstest document. And I aware of using 1-d array for operation such as ".T" would give not-so-expected results. My concern is 1-d array gives advantage of using kstest but at the same time disadvantage of using operation such as ".T" in Python, which is not a good and consistent way in application.